# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Firestore.snapshot_

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase for my cloud functions in my flutter app.
For some reason, my cloud function is not working. This is the console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Firestore.snapshot_ (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:709:128) at beforeSnapshotConstructor (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:146:30) at changeConstructor (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.js:150:49) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:34)

This is my cloud function code:

```
exports.onSendingNotificationsReceived3 = functions.firestore.document('/orders/{documentId}')

          .onCreate(async (snap, context)  => {
       // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore

          snap.data()['items'].forEach((result,index) =>{
          functions.logger.log('Token loop entered');
            //Getting list of shopIds from the items list in order

             if(listOfFCMToks.includes(result['fcmToken'])==true){
                functions.logger.log('Token already exists');
             }else{
        listOfFCMToks.push(result['fcmToken']);
        functions.logger.log('Token of shop is added');
                  }


          });
         /* snap.data()['shipperTokens'].forEach((result,index) =>{
                                        functions.logger.log('ShipperToken loop entered');
                                          //Getting list of shopIds from the items list in order

                                           if(listOfFCMToks.includes(result)==true){
                                              functions.logger.log('Token already exists');
                                           }else{
                                      listOfFCMToks.push(result);
                                      functions.logger.log('ShipperToken loop entered'+index);
                                                }


                                        });*/
            functions.logger.log('3');/*
             const shopRef = admin.firestore().collection("shops");
             const querySnapshot = await shopRef.get();
             querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                   functions.logger.log('4');
                   listOfShopIds.forEach(async (item) =>{
                       if(item==doc.data()['sid']){
                        functions.logger.log('55');
                        allChecksids.push(doc.data()['sid']);
                        const tokenRef = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(doc.data()['sid']).collection('tokens').doc('fcmToken');
                        const tokenCurrent = await tokenRef.get();
                        functions.logger.log('6');
                       functions.logger.log('88');
                         listOfUserTokensForFCM.push(doc.data()['token']);


                         listOfUserTokensForFCM.push('DataIsFound');

                       }
                   });

                   });*/

            functions.logger.log('66');
             await admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
        tokens : listOfFCMToks,
      notification: {
            title: "A NewOrder is Placed",
          body: "Please check your dashboard in Telloo App",
   imageUrl: "https://firebasestorTage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learning-firebase-2d636.appspot.com/o/newOrder.jpg?alt=media&token=71ad7cc8-6be6-4069-b097-75cc4f437978g",
                                                                                                   },
             }) .then((response) => {
                           console.log(
                             "Notifications are sent"
                           );});
            return snap.ref.set({listOfFCMToks}, {merge: true});
            });
```

Each order contains different items from multiple shop. I'm accessing fcmToken and trying to save them in a list in the same order with the cloud function use this code:

```
snap.data()['items'].forEach()
```

The function was working properly. But now I'm facing the error given above in the console.
To check if this isn't the problem with the syntax of function, I created another function and tested  it:

```
exports.getOrderId = functions.firestore
                                    .document('/orders/{documentId}')
                                    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
                                      // Get an object representing the document
                                      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
                                      const newValue = snap.data();

                                      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
                                      const name = newValue.orderId;
                                      functions.logger.log($name);

                                      // perform desired operations ...
                                    });
```

But upon testing this function, I'm getting the same error:

```
getOrderIdxtsp49f33azi ReferenceError: $name is not defined at exports.getOrderId.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:147:60) at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:23) at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:140:25) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

What solution I found from internet:
**Soution: Change node version to 8.**
But from now we can't use functions under node 10.
Help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `snap.data()['items'].forEach()`? Is `items` a field in the doc that triggered the Cloud Function? Also, are you sure that this is the code that triggers the eerror? We don't see `name` in this code.

Comment: `items` is a field of array that contains ordererd items from different shop. Purpose is to access fcmtokens from each item. Function was working fine. Probably due to the upgradation of flutter or node have caused this issue. I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: The constant is called `name` not `$name`? @SkillzUPPTechnologies Otherwise the error message would be `name is not defined at ...` instead of `$name is not defined at...`